# Can't run python programme opening its in text editor

Tags: python, programming

Guys...
I want to run a program for test our typing speed...
It worked well in ubuntu 14.04 but can't in the latest version ubuntu 17.10
Can anybody help me??
Link of programe:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3w5afjVfJirVkdsX1ltMklINUU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in 16.04, when started normally the program just does nothing and exits. Do you see the same symptom?
I found out using the python debugger (`pdb ./pytypespeed-0.04.py`) that the program is missing the *glade* library. The program unfortunately neglects to print an error message in line 22.

To fix, install glade with `sudo apt-get install python-glade2`.